# Jpa mapping of composite key

Tags: java, database, jpa, entity-relationship, openjpa

Hi Below is my tables and its desc.

```
Employee:
emp_Id primary_key
emp_Name 
emp_Address

Address:
emp_id -- foreign key of employee table
addres_type
type_id

AddressType:
Type_id  -- foreign key of Address table
Type
Desc
```

How can i create JPA entities with this relationship.

Thanks in advance

Comment: in POJO you would have in address class an employee instead of emp_id, same for addresstype. but i think this requires the foreign key to be the pk of the joining table, just like for employee and address

Comment: Which IDE do you use? Most IDE's provides the feature for generating Entity class from database tables, your table relationship should be defined at the database level and it should be accurate in order to see the desired results or output.

Comment: Your tables make no sense. I would fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

you'd better use **AbstractPersistable** to generate the id :

so Address and AddressType will have a primary_key also

1-Employee

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "Employee ")
    public class Employee extends AbstractPersistable<Long>{

// Employee here have a generated id from AbstractPersistable

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Column(name = "emp_Name ")
        private String emp_Name ;


        @ManyToOne(optional = true)
        @JoinColumn(name = "emp_Address")
        private Address emp_Address;
    }
```

2-Address

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "Address")
    public class Address extends AbstractPersistable<Long>{

    //Address here have a generated id from AbstractPersistable

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

//you can delete this column because you have already the ManyToOne in Employee 
        @ManyToOne(optional = true)
        @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id")
        private Employee emp_id;
//*****************

        @Column(name = "addres_type")
        private String addres_type;


        @ManyToOne(optional = true)
        @JoinColumn(name = "Type_id")
        private AddressType Type_id  ;
    }
```

3-AddressType

```
  @Entity
        @Table(name = "AddressType")
        public class AddressType extends AbstractPersistable<Long>{

       //AddressType here have a generated id from AbstractPersistable

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



            @Column(name = "Type")
            private String Type;

            @Column(name = "Desc")
            private String Desc;
        }
```

Comment: Where does he say anything about using Spring Data?

Comment: Yes he didn't , it's just a proposal

Comment: @vinod , there is  id in Employee table extended from AbstractPersistable